# compare magnitude and direction use of set_intersection ( common elements)?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to compare magnitude and direction for 16 images ( N = 4 , M  = 4 ) and check for a continuity between them.

So , I am comparing image 0 with image 1,image 2...image 15.

Then, image 1 ,with image 2,image 3 ..image 15.

Every image has dimensions 200x200 and CV_32F type.

I have a :

```
vector<Mat> smallImages;
smallImages.reserve( N * M ); //( N = 4 , M  = 4 )
```

I have calculated the gradients :

```
    vector<Mat> grad_x;
    vector<Mat> grad_y;
    grad_x.resize( N*M );
    grad_y.resize( N*M );

    // gradients x and y 
    for ( int idx = 0; idx < N*M; idx++ )
    {
        Sobel( smallImages[ idx ], grad_x[ idx ], ddepth, 1, 0, 3, scale, delta, BORDER_DEFAULT );
        Sobel( smallImages[ idx ], grad_y[ idx ], ddepth, 0, 1, 3, scale, delta, BORDER_DEFAULT );
    }
```

Then,the magnitude and direction:

```
    // magnitude and direction
    vector<Mat> magnitude;
    vector<Mat> direction;
    magnitude.resize( N*M );
    direction.resize( N*M );

    for ( int idx = 0; idx < N*M; idx++ )
    {
        cartToPolar( grad_x[ idx ], grad_y[ idx ], magnitude[ idx ], direction[ idx ] );
    }
```

Then , I am trying to compare ( for example for magnitude like [this])[1](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_intersection/):

```
    vector<Mat> MagnitudeComp;
    MagnitudeComp.resize( N*M * N*M );

    std::vector<cv::Mat>::iterator it;
    std::sort( magnitude.begin(), magnitude.end() );


    it = std::set_intersection( magnitude.begin(), magnitude.end(),    direction.begin(), direction.end(), MagnitudeComp.begin() );
    MagnitudeComp.resize( it - MagnitudeComp.begin() );
```

I am not sure why std::sort doesn't work ( a lot of errors like:)

```
/usr/include/c++/5.2.0/bits/predefined_ops.h:71:25: error: cannot convert ‘cv::MatExpr’ to ‘bool’ in return
       { return __val < *__it; }
```

I don't know if there is a better method to obtain what I want ( a matrix for holding magnitude and direction differences).

I know that I can do :

cv::sort( magnitude, magnitude, CV_SORT_EVERY_ROW + CV_SORT_ASCENDING );

but I am not sure if then I can do the `std::set_intersection`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason `std::sort()` doesn't work is that by default it uses `operator <()` for the value types, which in your case are matrixes.  Since [comparing](http://opencv.itseez.com/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=compare#compare) two matrixes results in a third matrix as output, it can't be used as the predicate for sorting.

So you need a predicate to order your matrixes (a "strict weak ordering" in the parlance).  I suppose the question is then back to you: how do you define the ordering of matrixes in your system?  Once you've done that, you need to implement a predicate like this:

```
bool matrixOrder(const Mat& m1, const Mat& m2);
```

And use it like this:

```
sort(magnitude.begin(), magnitude.end(), matrixOrder);
```

Comment: :I can use the cv::sort. My problem is how I can find the common elements between 2 matrices ( magnitude[0] and magnitude[1] ) for example.

Comment: Can you more clearly define "common elements"?  Are two elements in a single matrix common?  Are two elements in different positions in two matrixes common?

Comment: I want to find what elements ( and probably their position also)  are similar between 2 matrices ( magnitude[0] and magnitude[1]  for example.) But , as I say in the beggining of the post .I want to compare for exampe magnitude[0] with magnitude[1],iwth magnitude[2] and so on.Then , magnitude[1] with magniude[2],with magnitude[3] and so on.

Comment: So if the element is 4 at (0,0) in one matrix and 4 at (1,0) in the next matrix, are those similar?  Or you only compare (0,0) with (0,0)?

Comment: :No ,they are not.I am comparing elements at specific position as you said.Thanks

Comment: Then I don't see how `set_intersection` can help you at all.  Instead, you should use `mat1 == mat2` which should call `Mat::compare()` that I linked to earlier, and produce a matrix of booleans.

Comment: :But then the output array won't have only 0 or 255?And how can I find then which element was?

Comment: You do `magnitude[0] == magnitude[1]` which produces a boolean matrix of the same size.  The result tells you which elements were the same--just iterate over all the elements and check which ones are true.

Comment: :I am doing : `Mat test = magnitude[0]==magnitude[1];

    for ( int i =0; i < 200; i++ )
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 200; j++ )
        {
            if ( test.at<float>(i,j) == 255 )
                cout << i << "\t" << j <<endl;
        }
        
    }    
    ` but I am not getting any output although I checked the test matrix and it is full with 0 and 255.

Comment: What is `test.at<float>(i,j)`?  Is that casting the bool to a float?  That doesn't make sense to me.  How about `test.at<int>(i,j) != 0`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98005/discussion-between-george-and-john-zwinck).